# How to deal with numBest(solver status) in cplex

Tags: cplex

Cplex gives me the error of numBest. I thought it is related with time-limit, but after i call cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Param::TimeLimit, 36000), this problem still exists.

Objective sense : Minimize

Variables : 78 [Box: 78, Qobj: 60]

Objective nonzeros : 30

Objective Q nonzeros : 116

Linear constraints : 48 [Equal: 48]

Nonzeros : 168

RHS nonzeros : 33

Variables : Min LB: -300.0000   Max UB: 300.0000

Objective nonzeros : Min : 2.200000    Max : 8.000000

Objective Q nonzeros : Min : 0.1800000 Max : 3.200000

Linear constraints : Nonzeros : Min : 0.02990608 Max : 1.000000

RHS nonzeros: Min : 0.01013009 Max : 1.544200

This is result of display prob stats. Are there any problems? Very Thanks!

@Daniel Junglas

Thanks for your help!
I tried setting CPX_PARAM_NUMERICALEMPHASIS to 1, but the problem still exists.
'''
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Param::Emphasis::Numerical, 1);
'''

When I set CPX_PARAM_DATACHECK to 2, it would give me some warning,

CPLEX Warning 1036: Decimal part of coefficient for variable 'u_1_0' in constraint 'dynamicConstr_2_0' looks like 9/52 in single precision.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually related to numerical issues. Check your problem data. For example, export the model to a SAV file and then in the interactive do

```
CPLEX> disp prob stats
```

This will show you statistics of the model data. There you can spot very small or large numbers as well as big ranges of coefficients.

You may also want to enable modeling assistance by setting [CPX_PARAM_DATACHECK](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/DataCheck.html) to 2.

If your data is clean then you can ask CPLEX to be extremely careful about numerics by setting [CPX_PARAM_NUMERICALEMPHASIS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/NumericalEmphasis.html) to 1.

Comment: thanks! i have posted my stats result, can you help me take a look?

Comment: Instead of posting your statistics as a new answer you should edit your original question and add the statistics there.
In any case, your statistics look fine and the warning you get seems safe to ignore. Did you try setting CPX_PARAM_NUMERICALEMPHASIS?

Comment: yes, I tried setting CPX_PARAM_NUMERICALEMPHASIS, but it still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems can be numerically hard even though the problem stats are ok. You mention warning 1036, do you just have one of those or many? Not sure it will help, but setting CPX_PARAM_DEPIND to 3 for example may be worth a try.

You are solving a qp. By default the barrier algorithm is used for that, for which numerics may be more challenging than for simplex. If you set CPX_PARAM_BARCROSSALG to 1 or 2, cplex will perform crossover after barrier.